# Firefox 106.0.3 ignoring `#fullscr-toggler { display:none!important; }` in `userChrome.css`?

Tags: firefox, browser, css, fullscreen, address-bar

I'm trying to use the Jupyter lab web interface on a smaller screen; I need the browser to be full-screen for it to be useable. Jupyter Lab uses its own HTLM-rendered menu at the top of the page. Infuriatingly, every time I go to use this menu, Firefox pops up the address+tab+bookmarks toolbars.

This immediately causes the interface to shift down, and the address+tab+bookmarks toolbars erroneously capture clicks intended for the Jupyter lab menu.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35836449/900749), I should be able to fix this behavior by adding

```
#fullscr-toggler { display:none!important; }
```

To `userChrome.css` and restarting the browser.
I have done this, and the problem persists. I have checked that I'm editing the `userChrome.css` for the correct profile, and I can confirm that other changes specified in `userChrome.css` DO take effect.

This leads me to believe that either:

1. Firefox 106.0.3 ignores `#fullscr-toggler{display:none!important;}` and the fix no longer works. OR
2. I've misunderstood the original question and this `userChrome.css` modification was never intended to solve the issue I'm facing. (and we need a new solution)

In any case, either (1) or (2) being true would make this a new, *non-duplicate* question. Any insights?

Comment: The answer you’re looking at is very old. The Firefox user interface has gone through multiple major changes since then. It is likely it simply no longer applies. // If you want, you can investigate yourself using the _Browser Toolbox_.

Comment: Furthermore, `userChrome.css` is disabled by default. Did you enable the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` setting?

Comment: @DanielB: " I have checked that I'm editing the userChrome.css for the correct profile, and I can confirm that other changes specified in userChrome.css DO take effect."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer on the Firefox Support Forums: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1324666

> div#fullscr-toggler has been moved to HTML namespace, so you need to update the code in userChrome.css
>
> *|div#fullscr-toggler {display:none!important;}

So you just need to add `*|` in front of what you already have.

I added this in my userChrome.css and it no longer shows the Firefox toolbars in F11 fullscreen mode.

```
*|div#fullscr-toggler {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this when I get back to the affected the machine. Hopefully it is better than my current solution, which was to paste together literally every other `userChrome.css` hack for this from the past 10 years, which resulted in completely hiding everything all of the time, which worked but makes the browser generally unusable :P

Comment: Well, it works! I wonder what `*|`, is that standard CSS? This would be even better with a dedicated key binding to hide/show, but this is very nice, thank you ( :

Comment: Pipe `|` is used to denote [namespace in standard CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@namespace) so I guess they use the `*` [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) to avoid having to specify a particular namespace.

Comment: Thanks! There now seems to be another issue, in that jupyter-lab seems to consume or disrupt the F11 key that toggles full-screen, and there is no key to toggle the menu bar, so ... open sessions are slightly irritating to close briefly, but overall this is a substantial improvement ( :